# Converting dynamic sql query's COUNT result to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search within the values (table names) returned from a query to check if there is a record and some values in that record are null. If they are, then I want to insert the table's name to a temporary table. I get an error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'count(*) 
FROM  step_inusd_20130618 WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL' to data type int.
```

This is the query:

```
  DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(150)
  DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
  DECLARE @test int

  SELECT @table_name =  tableName FROM  #temp WHERE id = @count

   SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
--ERROR is below:
select @test =   'count(*) FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
   --PRINT @sql
  -- EXEC(@sql)
   IF @test > 0 
   BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO #temp2 (tablename) VALUES ( @table_name);
   END
  SET @count = @count + 1
```

Any ideas how to convert the result of the count into an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) where you may define output parameters.

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @test int

SELECT @table_name =  tableName FROM  #temp WHERE id = @count

DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @test = count(*) FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@test int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @test=@test OUTPUT;

IF @test > 0 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO #temp2 (tablename) VALUES ( @table_name);
    END
SET @count = @count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be "SET" instead of "select" ?

E.g., changing:

```
select @test =   'count(*) FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
```

for:

```
SET @test =   'select count(*) FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your problem is, that $test variable is INT and you are trying to assign to it the TEXT value 'count ...'

Use aproach like:
SELECT somevalue INTO myvar FROM mytable WHERE uid=1;

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed out the stuff not needed to show how to do this, so here it is:

```
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @CountStatement NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @test int

SELECT @table_name =  tableName FROM  #temp WHERE id = @count

SET @CountStatement = 'select @test = count(*) FROM  ' + @table_name + ' WHERE jobDateClosed IS NULL'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @CountStatement, N'@test INT OUTPUT', @test OUTPUT;
SELECT @test
```